# DBI - connect to MSSQL - unexpected login incorrect

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I'm using DBI 1.624... and trying to connect SQL Server 2012. I wrote perl script to get data from db, and tested it on test server. It works fine. I repeated everything for other server and now I can not connect to db with error: Login Incorrect.

I created new login with SQL Authentication and I can login with it via SQL Server Management Studio, but when I try to connect via DBI:

```
DBI->connect('dbi:Sybase:server=SERVERNAME.domain.com:3180;database=master', 'user', 'pass')
```

I always get error:

```
DBI connect('server=SERVERNAME.domain.com:3180;database=master','user',...) failed: OpenCilent message:
LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (36)
Server SERVERNAME.domain.com:3180, database
Message String: Login incorrect.
```

User settings:

- SQL Server authentication
- Server Roles: public, sysadmin
- Securables: Connect SQL
- Status: Permission to connect to database engine: Grant / Login: Enabled

Server settings:

- Connections: Allow remote connections to this server

Comment: What port is SQL Server running on? The connection string seems to point at 3180, which would not be a default port for SQL Server (that's 1433 or 1434).

Comment: It's running on 3180. If I try 1433/1434 - I get: Server is unavailable or does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My second server has all databases encrypted... So I use ODBC driver.